# How is it possible to set the response Header Content-Type to application/xml in APIGateway/Swagger

Tags: swagger, aws-api-gateway

How do you configure Swagger/APIGateway to set the response Header property Content-Type to be "application/xml" for an APIGateway Lambda GET endpoint that consumes and produces xml?

Currently the response Header Content-Type value is"application/json"

I was attempting to specify it like this:-

```
"/v1/XXXXXXX": {
  "get": {
    "produces": [
      "application/xml"
    ],
    "responses": {
      "200": {
        "description": "Meter reading data",
        "schema": { ........ }
      }
    },
    "x-amazon-apigateway-integration": {
      "responses": {
        "default": {
          "statusCode": "200",
          "responseParameters": {
            "method.response.header.Content-Type": "'application/xml'"
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

This was erroring as follows:-

```
Errors found during import: Unable to put integration response on 'GET' for resource at path '/v1/XXXXXXXXX': Invalid mapping expression specified: Validation Result: warnings : [], errors : [Invalid mapping expression parameter specified: method.response.header.Content-Type]
```

Much thanks,

Sam

Answer (score 0):

**Content-Type** should be added as a **mapping templates**.
you're setting it under  "responseParameters", this is incorrect.

set 'application/xml' under either:

1. "x-amazon-apigateway-integration":"requestTemplates"
2. "x-amazon-apigateway-integration":"responses": "responseTemplates"